# mongoDb fetch value from multi object key search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've a search parameter which has a combination of 3 fields (dwelling, nameOrNumber and street) and on keyup event I need to combine the above mentioned 3 keys and fetch the value from MongoDB

Sample Search Parameter:

```
"Plot 227, Rockingham Street"
```

Sample MongoDB Object

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5460e1660ca8560b00048e47"),    
"address" : {
            "dwelling" : "The Patterdale",
            "nameOrNumber" : "Plot 227",
            "street" : "Rockingham Street",
            "locality" : "Fitzwilliam",
            "town" : "Pontefract",
            "county" : "West Yorkshire",
            "postcode" : "WF95BZ",
            "country" : {
                "code" : "UK",
                "name" : "United Kingdom"
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you mean when you say "Combine the 3 keys and fetch"? Is there a set format?

Comment: @tantalum In the above MongoDB object sample I've 3 keys "dwelling", "nameOrNumber" and "street". When user search for a particular keyword I need to match all the 3 key value to fetch the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [creating `text indexes`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/), which can be created on [`multiple fields`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) as well.  And then use the [`$text`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator in your find query to perform the search, which will look at all fields indexed with a text index.  From the documentation:

> MongoDB provides text indexes to support text search of string content in documents of a collection.

For example, you can create an index like:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex(
                           {
                             dwelling: "text",
                             nameOrNumber: "text",
                             street: "text"
                           }
                         )
```

And then query like:

```js
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "Plot 227 Rockingham Street" } } )
```

That should find the document you are looking for.

**Note:**  The above example is untested.  However, the info provided should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Anand. But its working fine in mongodb 2.6.1.